# is there any way to control the threads based on the objective they're "attached" to?

Tags: java, java-threads

i need to set a thread priority, based on an object its "attached" to, i thought i might be able to get its ID somehow and then just give it a priority.

i tried to make my object static that way they'll be reachable, but i just cant control the thread based on its object.

in short, im trying to print something, and in the middle of the printing proccess the other threads are interrupting and printing stuff of thier own, without the current thread finished his print. thats why im trying to give it a priority. i've tried some pooling, but i discovered im not allowed to use that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Thread priority (which may or may not actually do anything). You should use a lock

```
public static final myLock = new Object();

public void print1() {
  synchronized(myLock) {
    ...
  }
}

public void print2() {
  synchronized(myLock) {
    ...
  }
}

public void print3() {
  synchronized(myLock) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: when i wrote the question in the "itried" section i wrote that i cannot use the synchronized methods

Comment: @InonLevy My answer isn't using synchronized methods - I am synchronizing on a common lock. But if you're not allowed to use locks because of arbitrary school assignment requirements, then maybe the *right* solution isn't the correct one for you. Do you want me to delete this?

Comment: OMG, thanks so much, u solved my problem! (i am allowed to use locks)

Comment: @InonLevy re: ... use locks! - Great! You should click the checkmark next to my answer to indicate that this answer solved your problem. You can also up click my answer if you want

Comment: @InonLevy re: ... use locks! - Great! You should click the checkmark next to my answer to indicate that this answer solved your problem. You can also up click my answer if you want